# mySql Constraint fields is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to constraint two different tables fields through mySql.
table(field) : comments(item_id) with item(item_ID) with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE 'comments' ADD CONSTRAINT comment_item
FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES items(item_ID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

but I'm getting this error message :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''comments' ADD CONSTRAINT comment_item
>
> FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES items(it' at line 1

what is the problem ? 
I'm using InnoDB as a Storage Engine, and utf_general_ci as a Collation .

Comment: I have written the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you dont need single quotes, according to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) you could write your statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT comment_item
FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES items(item_ID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

You can also check [here for an example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ALTER TABLE 'comments' ADD CONSTRAINT comment_item
```

to

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` ADD CONSTRAINT comment_item
```

Use ` instead of '.

or just write without `'` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE comments
```